# How can compress file or image in hayageek js file upload plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

During file upload, I need to compress or reduce the size of a file or image. The maximum allowed file size is specified as 16MB. Therefore, if the file or image size exceeds 16MB even after compression, it should not be uploaded.

Attaching my code block as well.

```
var upload_id=null;
var uploader = $(" #fileuploader").uploadFile({
    url: "/ezekyc/kyc/upload",
    fileName: "file",
    enctype: "multipart/form-data",
    sequential: true,
    sequentialCount: 1,
    maxFileSize: 16 * 1024 * 1024,
    autoSubmit: false,
    acceptFiles: "jp/*",
    dynamicFormData: function(file, xhr, pd)
    {
         upload_id = $("input[name='upload_id']:checked").val();
        var data = {
            "kycId": ezekyc.kycId,
            "documentType": upload_id,
            "pageNumber": findUploadCount(ezekyc.uploadedDocuments)
        };
        return data;
    },
    onSuccess: function(files, data, xhr, pd) {
        if (data.success) {
            if (ezekyc && data.kyc && data.kyc.uploadedDocuments)
                ezekyc.uploadedDocuments = data.kyc.uploadedDocuments;
            $('.ajax-file-upload-container').find('.ajax-file-upload-statusbar').each(function(index){
                               var name=('.ajax-file-upload-filename',$(this) ).text();
                               if(name && files &&  files[0] && name.search(files[0]) ){
                                      $(this).remove();
                               }
        });
    }
    },
    onError: function(files, status, errMsg, pd) {
        cancel();
        hidecardAggr11(upload_id);
    },
    afterUploadAll:function(obj)
    {
         loadup();
         hidecardAggr11(upload_id);
         console.log("loaded all");
    }
 });

var cancel = function() {
    uploader.stopUpload();
};

$("#extrabutton").click(function() {
    if(uploader.selectedFiles==0){
        toast("Please select files to upload");
    }
    uploader.startUpload();
});

$("#clearButton").click(function() {
    uploader.cancelAll();
});
```

I tried to use pako plugin with hayageek plugin but it is not working

```
beforeSend: function(file, xhr, pd) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(e) {
      var compressedData = pako.gzip(e.target.result);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
      pd.data = compressedData;
      pd.filename = file.name + '.gz';
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  },
```